# My react Native app keeps closing when I navigate back to it from another app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I noticed during development that my react native app closes when I navigate away from it to another app. The app itself is not a ram intensive one.

When I navigate to another app, say chrome for instance and navigate back to the app, it closes and I have to open it again. It's the same with the release build.

To the best of my knowledge, most apps will simply restart the main activity but mine completely shuts down and take you back to the home screen.

[Click here to view a preview](https://youtube.com/shorts/2gQTVYx7NHU?feature=share)

Please how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android manifest.xml add this line in the activity tag

`android:launchMode="singleTop"`

And in android mainApplication.java add this function.

```
@Override 
public void invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() 
{ moveTaskToBack(true); }
```

This will make sure that your app reopens from where you have left it